# Blender camera rotation issues

Tags: camera

I am trying to rotate my Camera (not the object but my vision), but it's stuck. I watched a many videos trying to fix it but nothing helped. Does someone have any idea about how to fix it?

I can't rotate my camera 360°. I am only able to zoom-in/zoom-out.

I tried to change my user preference by checking and un-cheking "emulate 3-button mouse". I tried restarting Blender and my pc. I uninstalled and reinstalled but my camera is still stuck in the same position.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=InwG2v6YvbQ&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please specify your question. You can rotate your camera with `R`, and `I` to create a keyframe of the object. Try posting a picture as well.

Comment: ok when you try to see around an objet  you simple hold the middle/right  click and drag i just can't make that its suck in the same position i just want to be able to turn around the object

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. Add images that might help us understand your scene.

Comment: ok i upload a video on youtube

Comment: Hold down the scroll button on your mouse and move the mouse around to move around in the viewport. [Take a look here.](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating#Panning_the_View)

Comment: i alredy tried that every single possible way to click

Comment: Since it seems to be box selecting there must be more input. Remove all IO-Hardware (except the mouse) like **keyboards, tablets, sliders** and try again.

Comment: ok i will try that :)

Comment: nop its not working i restarted my blender without any keyboard or pen/tablet and still not working

Comment: ok ! i finally found a way to fix it i change my control in file -> User Preference-> 3d view -> 3d view global -> rotate view -> and change it to right click

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a way to fix it. I changed my controls in `File -> User Preferences -> 3d View -> 3d View Global -> rotate view` and changed it to `right click`.